# how to implement code for canvas for moving image?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi how is the canvas code for moving image from one potion to another potion, in order to whenever we click on the the stop button moving image will be stop so plz help me to implement the coding.

Comment: your answer fine but my problem is how is the code move the image (doll) from initial position to some distance when we click on the start button and animation will be stop when click on the stop button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hai laxman download this code at url,it may help u

https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin